# Calling Graphviz dot from Java

Tags: java, graphviz

What's the best way to call an external program (graphviz's dot in this case) from a Java program and grab the output?

Comment: In the case of Graphviz, it might be better to invoke it in-process as a library rather than forking to the `dot` executable. Graphviz includes low-level SWIG-generated Java bindings; [jGraphViz](http://jgraphviz.sourceforge.net/) is a separate project that builds a higher-level Java API on the low-level SWIG bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Runtime.exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) and [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) do it.
You use one of them to create your process, then call its `getInputStream` to get the output stream of the launched process.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Graphviz Java API class](https://github.com/jabbalaci/graphviz-java-api) which is a wrapper for Runtime.exec(), this is if you have the dot binaries on the same server as your Java App.

If you don't have dot installed on the server or if you are using an environment like Google AppEngine where you can't install dot binaries locally then you can use [Graphviz Server](https://github.com/omerio/graphviz-server), a lightweight Java based HTTP server, you still need to install the dot binaries on the server on which you run Graphviz Server.

Comment: The "Graphviz Java API class" link is dead (404) unfortunately.