# Java, GraphViz and NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, graphviz

In the context of a project; I have to show my graph with GraphViz from read file .dot,
I work on windows; netbeans, and java.
is there someone who already use this tool?
I want to know is what I need to add a plugin for NetBeans?;

What I have to add to this environment so I can get the desired graphs; there 'til a JAVA API add?
﻿

Answer (score 0):

You need to call graphviz/dot from your java application. I am using exactly your setting (NetBeans on MAC) and outputting Graphs through Graphviz API. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26482170/294458).